# Execute batch file on remote PC from a webpage on user action

Tags: c#, batch-file, process, powershell-remoting

I have a webpage written in MVC C#. I want to run some batch file (on a remote PC) on user action in this page. I have the following function to run batch files on remote PC:

```cs
public bool runBatch(string address, string batchFile, string pwd, string username) {
    try {
        string AppPath = address;

        string strFilePath = AppPath + batchFile;
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = strFilePath;
        proc.StartInfo.UserName = username;
        proc.StartInfo.Domain = "localdomain";
        System.Security.SecureString secret = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char c in pwd)
            secret.AppendChar(c);

        proc.StartInfo.Password = secret;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        proc.Start();

        while (!proc.HasExited) {
            proc.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        proc.Close();

        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

and I call this function like this:

```cs
var run = runBatch("X.X.X.X:\\\\C:Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\", "ping.bat", "****", "Admin");
```

My PCs are in same IP domain and I have checked username and passwords multiple times, but I got an error

> username and password incorrect

I'm really confused.can any one help me with that?

Comment: `X.X.X.X:\\C:Users\Admin\Desktop\ping.bat` is not a valid UNC path, not to mention that invoking a remote script via an UNC path still would run it on the local host, not the remote host. Also, is the user a local account on the remote host or a domain account?

Comment: So how can i give the path for my batch file on remote PC?? the user is a local account. it's the PC's admin account. What can i do now?

Comment: Assuming that X.X.X.X is an IP from the remote desktop you want to access the correct UNC path would be: `\\\\X.X.X.X\\$c\\users\\Admin\\Desktop` I think. `$c` is a network share automatically created by windows which is active by default and creates access to the systemdrive.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 I tried what you said but i got the same error!! :(

Comment: UNC paths have the structure `\\server\share[\path]`, in your case `\\x.x.x.x\C$\Users\Admin\Desktop\ping.bat`. The domain for a local account is the computername of that host, not "localdomain". But that would still run the batch file on the local computer (i.e. the webserver), not on the remote computer (`x.x.x.x`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers oh thank you very much. It solved my problem. I was ignoring that this path is in the shared area.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers your answer helped me allot with machines in same domain. but what if I want to run process on another domain? I can browse that folder in another domain and I gave domain name with username. but when i run it from my program i got the error "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password". can you help me with that??

Comment: Local user is local.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I know. I have changed domain name to PC's domain. it's not local now. but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: If you modified the code, please update your question with the modified code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of friends help me with this question I will answer so maybe it can save time for another one. The problem with my code was that i was giving file adrress in a wrong way and. I have to call it like this:

```
var run = runBatch(@"\\x.x.x.x\C$\Users\Admin\Desktop\", "ping.bat", "****", "Admin");
```

Another thing to remember is that process can see shared folders on the path we gave!